# mvc 3 to mvc 5 migration razor syntax issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

We used official tutorial for upgradation, after following, we got no build errors, after running some functionalities are not working. We saw that some razor syntax were showing red as syntax error/some closing tag missing. what may be the reason

edit:
The errors as below image 
http://p.lui.li/img-40102_1_p-r-full.png 
and another sample 
http://p.lui.li/img-40102_2_p-r-full.png

there are still errors like div tag is not closed.
**All these codes were working fine in mvc3**

Comment: care to invest a couple more minutes in your request for help and explain what's the error and what's not working?

Comment: *what may be the reason?* who knows. All you've said is that it doesn't work. You haven't even said **what** doesn't work let alone show some code that is causing you problems.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: As Anirudga suggests, try keeping the new MVC 5 web.config file and integrating your older config into it.

Comment: I am trying this in visual studio 2012, sample code is attached

Comment: Those screenshots of your code are too small to get the overview and find the wrong/missing characters. Show us your entire view so we can find the problem.

Comment: this code is just after mvc 5 migration. The code is unchanged and no missing/wrong characters was showing in mvc 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem yesterday when I convert my old 3.0 project to MVC 4. in 2013 ViewBag and something also not found in current context even it's work fine in browser.

Make a new app with same namespace and copy paste the stuff carefully. After doing this your project will work like a charm.

Comment: Remember that don't use old web.config file. You need to stay with new created new web.config which is generated by VS.

Comment: We created a new MVC 5 template in VS 2012 and copied all the views and controllers and models. Copied the old web.config, Now its working like charm. Thanks